# Terminal seems to be appears to be cutting off a bash command midway

Tags: linux, macos, bash, terminal, stdout

I'm running a bash script on OSX Yosemite and Mavericks.
When I run the script the last line seems to be getting cut off part way. The last command loads a daemon - this is how it appears in the script:

```
sudo -u <USERNAME> launchctl load -w -F /Library/LaunchAgents/ExecuteScriptProcess.plist
```

It seems that once out of 10 or so times that I run this script the last command will not work. This is the output I'm receiving in the terminal:

`: No such file or directoryocess.plist`

Note how part of the filename `ocess.plist` was essentially concatenated to the end of the output and the name of the command does not appear before the colon.

This behaviour seems to show up randomly. Has anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 0):

This is due to carriage returns in your script or data. The [bash tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) has more information:

1. **Check whether your script or data has DOS style end-of-line characters**

   - Use `cat -v yourfile` or `echo "$yourvariable" | cat -v` .

     DOS carriage returns will show up as `^M` after each line.

     If you find them, delete them using `dos2unix` (a.k.a. `fromdos`) or `tr -d '\r'`